# Prevent vaadin to start up in integration test

Tags: spring-boot, integration-testing, vaadin

whenever I start up my integration tests (@SpringBootTest) and the application context is started, it also runs through the entire vaadin start up routine. this can take a few moments (~ 2 mins currently) until "Vaadin application has been deployed and started to the context path "/"." is displayed.

for some of my ITs I don't need vaadin, because I just test some other interfaces and I wonder if I can prevent vaadin to boot during selected tests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to exclude the following auto configurations of Vaadin:

- VaadinScopeConfig
- SpringSecurityAutoConfiguration
- SpringBootAutoConfiguration

All three are located at `com.vaadin.flow.spring`.